# Question removed

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

Yesterday I asked a question about web development, here's [the link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84062/starting-web-development-and-interactive-experiences)

But the question was removed, and I wanted to look back at it. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

There was an issue last night with migrations due to an unrelated push, causing this to migrate multiple times.  In correcting it we deleted all the duplicates, but unfortunately we deleted the one that the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349835/starting-web-development-and-interactive-experiences?noredirect=1) question [points](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84062/starting-web-development-and-interactive-experiences) to as well...oops.

I undeleted [that question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84062/starting-web-development-and-interactive-experiences) (the same you linked in *this* question) to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna have to ask around why it was removed. As I mentioned in my comment to Josh, there was a [problem with migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95153/same-questions-migrated-multiple-times) last night, but the other two questions that were affected seem to still be around. I'm not sure why this one was removed.

Edit: Looks like it was just deleted by accident during the clean-up after fixing the problem I linked to above. It's been restored now.